# Open Recent instead of My Drive in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

Is it posible to open Google Drive on Recent items instead of My Drive?

I saw the website opens the url https://drive.google.com/drive/#my-drive, and what I need is to open https://drive.google.com/drive/#recent by default.

I'm using google apps.

Comment: Why not just make yourself a shortcut that points to the URL you want?

Comment: @AlE. is there isn't other choice, I will. What I'm asking is, if there is an option for it.

Comment: Not that I can see. Other apps offer a setting like "use X as start page". I don't see any such option in Google Drive. Admittedly, I only have the consumer version; I'm not using Google Apps.

Comment: This would be useful. I looked under keyboard shortcuts too and no such luck. Although, the "/" shortcut allows you to start searching.